# Attempt to set a non-property-list object custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, info.plist

I've been struggling with an existing project which uses .plist to save the data from the user which is logged in.

On crashlytics I've found a problem which results in a crash. When a user updated his profile in the web-application it causes a crash in the application.

The error says it's because I'm trying to set a non-property-list object. But I've already tried to add all the fields into the .plist-file.

[image: Error & .plist]

Here you can see the changed .plist

[image]

I'm not sure but I think there is something wrong with the value "street"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the problem might come from the 'street' object. Because according to your plist, it should be a 'text', but it seems to be an NSArray...

To get the text value you should do something like that :

```
NSString *streetString = ((NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"street"]).firstObject;
```

And save that value instead.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it still crashes because:

[VUtil setUserAddressDictionaryToUserDefaults:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[responseArray firstObject]]];

which results in this function

+ (void)setUserAddressDictionaryToUserDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:dict forKey:KEY_USER_ADDRESS];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

Comment: I'm not sure to understand...
But it seems that [responseArray firstObject] isn't a dictionary. You should write something like this instead : @{@"street":[responseArray firstObject]}